# Is it possible to access the live tweets of a user using tweepy?

Tags: twitter, tweepy, tweets

I am trying to access live tweets of a user whenever he tweets it. So, all I want is something that continuously monitors a user account and whenever he tweets something I have to capture it. All the tweets are random so I cannot use any filters.

For any security reasons, if I cannot access other's tweets can I do it on my own account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With tweepy you can connect to the REST API or the Streaming API.
Using the Streaming API you can use the filter endpoint to select the users you wish to follow with that streaming connection and you will receive updates as they get published.

Twitter's documentation: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/filter, tweepy's code: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/streaming.py

Tweepy's documentation doesn't give examples on the Streaming functions but you can find sample code searching at GitHub or StackOverflow for "tweepy filter follow".

Answer (score 0):

Tweepy talks to the Twitter REST API, and the REST API doesn't have any way to react to someone posting a tweet.

HOWEVER...

You could certainly write an application that retrieves the tweets of a partcular user and looks for any tweets that weren't there the last time you checked.

You'd want to be cautious about how often you check so you don't run afoul of the API rate limits.